# PHP PDO PostgreSQL Could Not Determine Data Type

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've been getting a strange error while using the PHP PDO with PostgreSQL for a specific query and I don't understand why.

I have the following code

```
$conn = new PDO($db, $us, $pw);

try {
   $count = $conn->prepare("select count(idno) as count from t_dummy where ( ? is null or idno = ? )");
   $count->execute([null, null]);
   $count_fetch = $count->fetch();
} catch(Exception $error) {
   echo $error;
}

var_dump($count_fetch[0]);
```

If the PDO is connected to a MySQL Database then it works fine but when connected to a PostgreSQL Database it fails with the following error

```
could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

It looks like it doesn't like taking a parameter for `? is null` but I don't know why as this is valid PostgreSQL syntax that works fine in PgAdmin

Comment: What's the point of `? is null`? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: It's a way of handling a null id, if the id parameter is null then the first condition is true and it counts all records, if the id is not null then the second condition is only true for the record matching the id number

Comment: Use a CAST() in your query, for example: CAST(? AS integer) IS NULL

Comment: Thank you @FrankHeikens that is exactly what I needed, could you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CAST():

```
$conn = new PDO($db, $us, $pw);

try {
   $count = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(idno) AS count FROM t_dummy WHERE ( CAST(? AS integer) IS NULL OR idno = ? );");
   $count->execute([null, null]);
   $count_fetch = $count->fetch();
} catch(Exception $error) {
   echo $error;
}

var_dump($count_fetch[0]);
```